# DNS for non-static address

Tags: windows-server-2008, dns, domain

I currently own a .com domain and to get some use to it I decided to setup a home server.
I'm using Windows Server 2008 (Not R2).

The problem comes when you have a domestic ip that can change from time to time (mine doesn't even change that much) that your ISP assigns to you and you want to setup a DNS server (That's what you need to use the .com domain right?).

So basically this is it. I think making the webserver itself after this won't be much of a problem. If it is tell me please.

As you can probably tell I'm very new to managing servers so please try to be as detailed as possible and please do write if you have a solution to my problem.

A good day of work for you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To manage the change of IP address you will need some sort of Dynamic DNS. [DynDNS](http://www.dyndns.com/ns) and others provide services that can do this.

Comment: +1, also see: http://serverfault.com/questions/1239/dynamic-dns

Comment: OpenDNS does not provide such a service.

Comment: @whitequark: Your correct I misunderstood the nature of opendns's dynamic dns.